# I can not access the Color.luminance static method

Tags: android

I am trying to change the colour luminance using the method `Color.luminance` in my android app but I keep getting the error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method luminance(I)F in class Landroid/graphics/Color; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.graphics.Color' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

On going to the declaration documentation of this static method I see:

```
/**
     * Returns the relative luminance of a color.
     * <p>
     * Assumes sRGB encoding. Based on the formula for relative luminance
     * defined in WCAG 2.0, W3C Recommendation 11 December 2008.
     *
     * @return a value between 0 (darkest black) and 1 (lightest white)
     */
    public static float luminance(@ColorInt int color) {
        ColorSpace.Rgb cs = (ColorSpace.Rgb) ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.SRGB);
        DoubleUnaryOperator eotf = cs.getEotf();

        double r = eotf.applyAsDouble(red(color) / 255.0);
        double g = eotf.applyAsDouble(green(color) / 255.0);
        double b = eotf.applyAsDouble(blue(color) / 255.0);

        return (float) ((0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b));
    }
```

Obviously it's there but at run time it errors out and I can't understand what is wrong, my code:

```
private float luminance = Color.luminance(color);
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.george.value"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`luminance (int color)` is added in api 24 and `luminance (long color)` in api 26 but your min sdk is 22

because your compile sdk is 27 code is compiled successfully but on devices with android 6 and lower you get this exception so change your min sdk version to 24 or find another solution

insted of changing min sdk you can use `ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(int color);` from `android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you suggest a workaround that will work with my `minSDK`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen use `ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(int color);`